# how to open a new window(2nd frame) when a button is clicked in present window(1st frame) in java swing

Tags: java, swing

so i have been working on a project where there is a "login" button in a frame which i have created and i have to make it so that when the user clicks the "LOGIN" button the present window should terminate and a new window with labels and textfields would open prompting the user to enter his username, pass i have made the other frame with textfield n labels just dont know how to link the two together,i have made two different classes for both the LOGIN button frame and userid pass frame and these classes are called from a seperate main class which has main function in it please help gotta submit project on monday :( :(

Comment: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

In `Login` button: add action to it which allow you to

```
       1- dispose the Login frame 
       2- open the second frame
```

Like this :

```
private void LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        dispose();////////////will dispose the Login frame
        UsernameAndPassword username = new UsernameAndPassword();//////UsernameAndPassword :is the second frame. 
        username .setVisible(true);//////the Username and password frame will be visible
    }
```